# Trouble with login page checking credentials in database - NextJS13 App

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to set up a login system for my nextJS 13 app. So far, I've successfully connected it to a Postgresql database, with a signup page that creates an account, using a Prisma model.

I'm now trying to get the login form to check if there are existing credentials in the database, so the user will be then redirected to the homepage.

I'm getting error after errr - I've read the nextJS documentation as well as Prisma, and am stuck on what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Server side - route.js file - in a folder called checkuser, so /api/checkuser is the url

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function checkUserCredentials(email, password) {
    try {
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: email,
            },
        });

        if (!user) {
            return false; // User with this email does not exist
        }

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        return passwordMatch;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking user credentials", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

export async function POST(request) {
    const { email, password } = await request.json();
    
    try {
        const isAuthorized = await checkUserCredentials(email, password);

        if (isAuthorized) {
            return NextResponse.json({ authorized: true });
        } else {
            return NextResponse.json({ authorized: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.error("Error checking user credentials");
    }
}
```

client side login form

```
"use client"

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"; 
import Link from "next/link";


export default function LogIn() {
    const { register, reset, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const router = useRouter();

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/api/checkuser", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                router.push("/");
                reset();
            } else {
              
                console.error("Registration failed");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="signUp">Log in</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="signUpForm">
      
                <input
                    {...register("email", { required: true })}
                    type="email" 
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    aria-invalid={errors.email ? "true" : "false"}
                />
                {errors.email && <p className="errorMessage" role="alert">Email is not registered</p>}

                <input
                    {...register("password", { required: true, minLength: 4 })}
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Password must contain a minimum of 8 characters"
                    aria-invalid={errors.password ? "true" : "false"}
                />
                {errors.password && <p className="errorMessage" role="alert">Please enter the correct password for this account</p>}

                <button type="submit" className="signSubmit">Submit</button>
                <p className="alreadyText"> Don`t have an account? <Link href="/sign-up"><span><strong>Sign up here</strong></span></Link></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What error are ou getting? Is the server returning the correct response?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `500` means something terrible is wrong with your API service. You need to check the logs further than just `500` error status and find out why the server is breaking with the request you made.

Answer (score 1):

Since you return the error only in `checkUserCredentials`:

```
async function checkUserCredentials(email, password) {
    try {
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: email,
            },
        });
        if (!user) {
            return false; // User with this email does not exist
        }
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        return passwordMatch;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking user credentials", error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

the error might be thrown in the `try` block. The only async code in `try block` is:

```
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: email,
            },
        });
```

`prisma` server did not understand this request. It might be because you did not set `unique`decorator for `email`. Your `user model` should be like this:

```
model User{
  id             Int         @id  @default(autoincrement())
  email          String      @unique
  created_at     DateTime    @default(now())
  updated_at     DateTime    @updatedAt    
}
```